# Android Studio 3.0 migration AAPT2 error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

After migrating my existing project to `Android Studio 3.0`, it is not compiling. Below are the log details:

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for 
details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 27s
Information:11 errors
Information:0 warnings
```

Comment: Could you add the logs? There should be an actual AAPT error just above the stacktrace.

Comment: I found that a simple rebuild also fixed the error for me. I tried the solutions given below at first and rebuilt it. I removed it and rebuilt again, and it still worked.

Comment: Update: Error came back, guess I'll just disable aapt2 again

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to your `gradle.properties` write the below code and Sync your project

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

[image]

Comment: `Process 'command 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
` after applying the above method. Any guess?

Answer (score 4):

Is your username in OS cyrillic? If so - you need to change the .gradle resource folder in settings to path which does not contain cyrillic symbols.
In `->Settings-> Build, Execution -> Gradle` change `Service directory path` to "C:/Users/Public/.gradle"

Comment: I also have a non-English character in my path and have the same problem. 


When I tried your suggestion, I get many errors, such as `error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.`

Upon examination I see that the .gradle directory is over 900MB.

I cannot add the suggested row to `gradle.properties` because I don't such that file in one of my projects. There's another called `settings.gradle` but adding the row there gives other errors.

Comment: If you can't find gradle.properties in your project, just create it as an empty file in the project's top level directory and add the setting to it.

Answer (score 0):

this problem occur when there is something wrong in your XMl file

1:- remove all unnecessary XML files from your code

2:- Reopen and Check XML files

If there is Still Problem

Go to your gradle.properties write the below code

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

and then Go to your build.gradle(app) write the below code and Sync your project

```
aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
```

[image: Like this Image]

**Note android.enableAapt2=false is deprecated, and will be removed by the end of 2018, so this doesn't solve the problem, is just a temporary workaround**