# Gradle build fails with error: Failed linking resources and AAPT2 error

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I try to run the project or try to rebuild it,it throws error:failed linking resources. Please see screenshot:[image: Error Message]

All the drawable are there still it is showing this.
And all the R of my java files are in red color when hover it shows a message cannot resolve symbol 'R'
See screenshot: [image: Java File Error]

Error is coming in every java file I open.

I tried Invalidating caches and cleaning project but nothing is working. Search everywhere but didn't find a solution.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: build.gradle(Module: app)

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle(Project:weMate)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shivamtiwari.wemate"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

After trying gradlew assembleDebug:

```
        Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.371]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate>gradlew assembleDebug
E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_account.xml:27: AAPT: error: resource drawable/uploaddisplay (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/uploaddisplay) not fo
und.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_car_pool.xml:9: AAPT: error: resource drawable/search_bar_bg (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/search_bar_bg) not fo
und.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_car_pool.xml:21: AAPT: error: resource drawable/search_bar_bg (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/search_bar_bg) not f
ound.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_car_pool.xml:33: AAPT: error: resource drawable/search_bar_bg (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/search_bar_bg) not f
ound.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_car_pool.xml:51: AAPT: error: resource drawable/search_bar_bg (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/search_bar_bg) not f
ound.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_car_pool.xml:64: AAPT: error: resource drawable/search_bar_bg (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/search_bar_bg) not f
ound.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_car_pool_list.xml:8: AAPT: error: resource drawable/list_row_selector (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/list_row_sel
ector) not found.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_helpdesk.xml:8: AAPT: error: resource drawable/search_bar_bg (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/search_bar_bg) not fo
und.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_shop_list.xml:8: AAPT: error: resource drawable/list_row_selector (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/list_row_selecto
r) not found.

E:\MCA\AndroidProject\weMate\app\src\main\res\layout\nav_header_main.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource drawable/side_nav_bar (aka com.shivamtiwari.wemate:drawable/side_nav_bar) not found.

error: failed linking file resources.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
13 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

Comment: just do FIle-->Invalidate Caches/Restart and clean and rebuild project.

Comment: As i mentioned above i have tried it several times, nothing happens

Comment: are you using custom drawable??

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47302422/5110595)

Comment: Try reducing the path length for the project, meaning: Try reducing folder name - length.

Comment: For java file error, simply build.gradle (Module:app) file, put a small change somewhere, like put a space at the end of the file and then remove it.  Option to sync on the top right corner will appear, sync it, it will solve the problem.

Comment: The R is red because the build failed before it was generated (it's generated during linking resources). What version of the gradle plugin are you using? If you're on 3.2.0-alpha9 or newer and you have drawables with language qualifiers there's a bug that will remove all of them that don't have a default in drawable/ (no qualifiers)

Comment: How to know about plugin@IzabelaOrlowska and how to resolve it

Comment: @Danger I have tried but when click on sync now it finishes with the same error message

Comment: Post the content of your build.gradle files - the info will be in there. Also go to the project directory and run "gradlew assembleDebug" and post the contents here

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I have edited question with build.gradle files. Have a look! And there is a file with name gradlew, should i post content of that file.

Comment: @ShivamTiwari no, don't post the contents of gradlew. Execute it with the task "assembleDebug" from the commandline: "gradlew assembleDebug"

Comment: @ShivamTiwari if it's easier you can upload your project to github/bitbucket and post the link so we can reproduce your error

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I have updated the question with the content of gradlew assembleDebug. Please check!

Comment: where did you put the drawable?

Comment: @ShivamTiwari can you post the content of the arc/main/res here? Like which file is where.

Comment: @ShivamTiwari Have you solved this? I am running into this problem now. And it is driving me crazy.

Comment: Hi I am facing similar issue. How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, After moving the resource files from Global drawable folder to specific drawable folder solved the issue.

For ex:
If your resource file is in the following path

```
/drawable/btn_bg.xml
```

Then moving it to

```
/drawable-hdpi/btn_bg.xml
```

will solve the problem.

Similarly any image files as well,

For ex:
If your resource file is in the following path

```
/drawable/welcome_illustration.png
```

Then move it to

```
/drawable-hdpi/welcome_illustration.png
```